# Undo the changes in listview onbackpressed

Tags: android, listview, onbackpressed

I have a list view which contains list of products and on the click of the list item, list details gets open. The list item contains values like gross weight, net weight etc.

On the top of the list item details page I have a cross button instead of back button which on click will open a dialog saying "Do you want to save the changes" and with the button yes or no.

On pressing YES, I am able to save the changes in the list view but on pressing NO, am not able to undo the changes.

Below is the code for showing the dialog:

```
@Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {

        final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        alert.setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.save_activity));
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setButton(getContext().getString(R.string.strYes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    saveAndClose();
            }
        });
        alert.setButton2(getContext().getString(R.string.strNo), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                alert.dismiss();
                ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return true;

    }
```

For the same, I have tried to create a array list with different reference and tried to set the values.

But it seems not working.

Please provide any solution for the same.

Comment: Mention your requirement

Comment: What do you expected? You only dismiss the alert and finish current activity when user press No. There is no undo code. Of course you are not able to undo the changes.

Comment: @Joshua, On the click of cross button, dialog pop ups which has YES or NO. On pressing YES, its should save the entered values to list and on pressing NO, the changes should not save , and the previous values should reflect when opening the list details from the list.

Answer (score 1):

There a simple way to achieve this

let's say you have a Product class

```
public class Product{
    private boolean currentState;
    private boolean previosState;
}
```

Maintain the **currentState** when user clicks on the cross button but do not touch the **previousState**.

Now on the yes or no selection when press Yes consider the **currentState** and when press No consider the **previosState**.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: @StackQuest the deal is simple, you keep the state of the currentState and do not touch the previousState. So when user presses the YES you consider the current state selection and when NO then previousState cause nothing changed to this variable and you can easily get the UNDO effect.

Comment: thanks, but the same , I have asked in the question, how to restore the previous state of my list view.? As I am new to android, i know the default behaviour of list view on back pressed but dont know how to save the previous state,please help

Comment: I mean how to implement the previous state, do u have any example.?