# Is it possible to revert the changes in a list view onbackpressed?

Tags: android, listview, onbackpressed

Sorry, I have asked a question before also regarding the same, but couldn't find any answer.

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995201/undo-the-changes-in-listview-onbackpressed)

Please help me with the clarification and suggestion for the same.

Can I revert the changes in the list view on pressing back button?
Or it is not possible to do that.

Comment: add some code and logcat error.

Comment: you will have to maintain a stack of the changes and override your onBackPressed, and keep on popping the stack whenever back is pressed. Although, you will have to carefully design you stack depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

you can reset the adapter or call notifydatasetchanged()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. but for that you have to manage your listview with previous state and updated positions.also you have to manage flag for isListUpdate or not so when you found that its true then undo changes as per you requirement. it all about logic. you have to do it your self in your code.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, do u have any example so that I could understand it better.

Comment: @StackQuest Dont have any  example. sry for that.